# Get list of target files from MSI

Tags: windows-installer

Is there any way to easily get a list with a full target files from MSI package file, without unpacking it? And store it, for example, in a text file?

---

#### Solved

Question resolved with a help of Christopher Painter, which already found the answer: [How can I resolve MSI paths in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611838/how-can-i-resolve-msi-paths-in-c)

Comment: What does the Windows-Installer section on MSDN say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resolve MSI paths in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611838/how-can-i-resolve-msi-paths-in-c)

Comment: bash.d, probably I missed something on MSDN, but, unfortunately, I didn't found anything that could easily get the list of files with full target file paths.

Comment: Christopher Painter, seems like it's all I need! Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve MSI paths in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611838/how-can-i-resolve-msi-paths-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use ORCA to open the msi, right click - export tables choose File table.

Comment: It will store just the file names, but not the full target file paths, that I need. Anyway, thanks for the reply.